# postgresql foreign table

Tags: postgresql

Доброе утро. почему во внешней таблице при запросе:

```
select max(id) from mssql_idtest
```

Выдаёт ошибку:

```
ERROR: DB-Library error: DB #: 170, DB Msg: General SQL Server error: Check messages from the SQL Server, OS #: -1, OS Msg: (null), Level: 15
SQL-состояние: HV00L
```

А если делать простой запрос:

```
 select id from mssql_idtest
```

Всё отлично работает.
PS.В таблице id нет не одного значения null

Comment: avg() и min() тоже работают.

Comment: повезло что это id A_I так что использовал count

Answer (score 0, accepted):

это id A_I так что использовал count